# Fluid layout with div stretched across the top of the entire layout

Tags: html, css

I have a fluid layout with two divs on the right and left which are elastic on resizing the page, and the center div has a max-width and a min-width.

Does anyone know how to make a div stretch across the entire page, that is above the current layout (on top)? Please make it work with the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SHnc9/13/) -- I want the div that stretches to be a fixed header that has a background.

```
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif;
    }
    .container {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .container > div {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .fixed {
        min-width: 200px; 
        max-width:300px;
        background: rgb(34, 177, 77);
        color: white;
    }
    .fluid {
        background: rgb(0, 162, 232);
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="fluid">
        I'm 150px wide! Glee is awesome!
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
        I'm fluid! Glee is awesome!
    </div>
    <div class="fluid">        
        I'm 150px wide! Glee is awesome!
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add a div above `<div class="container">`. If you don't apply any styles to it, it'll already stretch to the full width. So:

```
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif;
    }
    .header {
        background: red;
    }
    .container {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .container > div {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .fixed {
        min-width: 200px; 
        max-width:300px;
        background: rgb(34, 177, 77);
        color: white;
    }
    .fluid {
        background: rgb(0, 162, 232);
    }
</style>

<div class="header">
    I'm a header! Hooray!
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="fluid">
        I'm 150px wide! Glee is awesome!
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
        I'm fluid! Glee is awesome!
    </div>
    <div class="fluid">        
        I'm 150px wide! Glee is awesome!
    </div>
</div>
```